# how to get all images list from resources sub folder in run time , after making run able jar file

Tags: java

**Step 1 : when I run my project in myeclipse at development mode then it runs perfectly.

Step 2 : So I make runable jar file 

Step 3 : I make run.bat file to run my project which is desktop application.**

On Step 3, file not found etc error is coming but when I run my desktop application in myeclipse then no error comes like file not found. It means after making runable jar file, my code is not able to find my images resources folder, this images resource is available on development mode.

Comment: When you make runnable jar , there is option in eclipse to include your code folders or not, you need to right check on that while exporting jar

Answer (score 0):

This could be because when you run in eclipse you run from files, so you can read images as regular files. When you run from jar, you don't have files anymore, you have only that jar. It has that images inside, but you need to read them using

```
InputStream is = YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream(packageAndFileName);
```

then you could use `ImageIO` class to read the stream into image

the root of the project is denominated by `"/"`,
so the path should be like

`"/packagePart1/packagePart2/fileName.ext"`